# alarm does not seem to fire if I set $SIG{ALRM}

Tags: perl, alarm

I'm trying to implement an alarm in my Perl backend process so that it will terminate if it gets stuck for too long. I tried to implement the code given on the [alarm documentation page on Perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm) (this is verbatim from the documentation other than the line that calls my program's key subroutine instead of the sample line in the documentation):

```
eval {
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "alarm\n" }; # NB: \n required
    alarm $timeout;
    &FaithTree::Backend::commandLine({ 'skipWidgets' => $skipWidgets, 'commandLineId' => $commandLineId, 'force' => $force });
    alarm 0;
};
if ($@) {
    die unless $@ eq "alarm\n";   # propagate unexpected errors
    # timed out
}
else {
    # didn't
}
```

Given this code, nothing happens when the alarm should have timed out. On the other hand, if I remove the custom definition for `$SIG{ALRM}` (which, again, came straight from the Perl documentation) the alarm does fire, just without the custom handler.

I'm wondering if the fact that I'm using `Thread::Queue` is playing a role in the alarm failing, but that doesn't explain why it works so long as I skip redefining `$SIG{ALRM}`.

Here's a minimal, runnable version with subroutine that is intentionally an infinite loop for testing:

```
eval {
    $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "alarm\n" }; # NB: \n required
    alarm 1;
    &FaithTree::Test::Backend::commandLine({ 'skipWidgets' => $skipWidgets, 'commandLineId' => $commandLineId, 'force' => $force });
    alarm 0;
};


if ($@) {
    die unless $@ eq "alarm\n";   # propagate unexpected errors
    # timed out
}
else {
   exit;
}


package FaithTree::Test::Backend;

use File::Tail;
use threads;
use threads::shared;
use Thread::Queue;

sub commandLine {

    our $N //= 4;
    my $Q = new Thread::Queue;
    my @kids = map threads->create( \&FaithTree::Test::Backend::fetchChild, $Q ), 1 .. $N;  

    my @feeds = ( "1","2","3","4" );

    foreach my $feed (@feeds) {
        $Q->enqueue( $feed );
    }

    $Q->enqueue( ( undef ) x $N );
    $_->join for @kids; 

}

sub fetchChild {

    print "Test";
    # Access queue.
    my $Q = shift;

    #What is my thread id?
    my $tid = threads->tid();

    my ($num, $num2);

    for ( ; ; ){ 
        if ($num2 == 10000) {
            say STDERR $tid . ': ' . $num;
            $num2 = 0;
        }
    
        $num++; 
        $num2++;
    }

    return 1;

}
```

If you comment out the `$SIG{ALRM}` line, it will terminate when the alarm is set to time out. If you leave it in place, it will never terminate.

Comment: Thread::Queue... so this a threaded program? Using signals in a threaded program doesn't really make sense since signals are sent to processes (not threads). Are you even setting `$SIG{ALRM}` in the main thread as per the threads.pm docs?

Comment: @ikegami Yes. This is all before it forks off into different threads. Each thread is a worker to check for content updates. The threads are not created (besides the main process itself, of course) until after that subroutine call you see above. The goal is to kill the whole thing if it gets stuck well beyond its planned runtime. I could be completely off base on Thread::Queue affecting this; I'm just trying to figure out why code straight out of the documentation isn't working.

Comment: I suppose if I could come up with a good way to monitor the runtime of /each/ thread and send the Perl `->kill()` to the said thread if it ran to long, that'd be cleaner than killing the whole process, but I was just trying to do something rudimentary to stave off a situation where the process never terminates (and subsequently blocks the next time cron starts it).

Comment: Re "*send the Perl ->kill() to the said thread if it ran to long*", That won't interrupt a system call or an XS call.

Comment: Maybe a watchdog setup would make more sense for you. Change the modified time on the the pid file every so often. The next time the cron job runs, it the modified time is older than allowed, kill the old task if it's still running. [Something like this could be done on a thread-by-thread basis, too.]

Comment: *"if I remove the custom definition for $SIG{ALRM}.."* You mean remove just the line: `local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "alarm\n" };` ?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal, runnable demonstration of the problem?

Comment: @ikegami I've added the code above. Thanks! A watchdog makes sense -- I actually had been reading ideas on how best to put one together and ran into one written in Perl. I probably should have just done that, but I thought, "What if I could make the program take care of itself?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signals and threads don't mix well. You might want to rethink your use of signals. For example, you could move all the thread stuff to a child process.

---

Signal handlers are only called between Perl ops. The main thread is in a call to XS sub `thread->join`, and the signal handler will be called once `join` returns.

Most blocking system calls can be interrupted (returning error `EINTR`), so it might be possible to write a signal-aware version of `join`. Except I seem to remember pthread functions not being interruptible, so maybe not.

---

In this particular case, you could have the threads signal the main thread when they are over using a system that allows the main thread to block until the a signal occurs or a timeout has occured. `cond_signal`/`cond_timedwait` is such a system.

```perl
use Sub::ScopeFinalizer qw( scope_finalizer );
use Time::HiRes         qw( time );

my $lock :shared;
my $threads_remaining = $N;
my $Q = new Thread::Queue;

my @threads;
{
   lock $lock;
   for (1..$N) {
      ++$threads_remaining;

      push @threads, async {
         my $guard = scope_finalizer {
            lock $lock;
            --$threads_remaining;
            cond_signal($lock);
         };

         worker($Q);
      }
   }
}

my $max_end_time = time + 1;

# ...

{
   lock $lock;
   while ($threads_remaining) {
      if (!cond_timedwait($lock, $max_end_time)) {
         # ... Handle timeout ...
      }
   }
}

$_->join for @threads;
```

Comment: Added to answer.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you! Would this solve an issue where one of the threads freezes? Or do I need to go more of the "watchdog" route you mentioned above in that case? I'm trying to isolate _why_ the one thread freezes, but one of them does and when it does, the backend is stuck until I notice, kill the process and start over.

Comment: Re "*Would this solve an issue where one of the threads freezes?*", Yes, you'll know it, since you're not blocked calling `join`, you're blocked calling `cond_timedwait`.

Comment: This seems to be working really well. Thank you! For debugging purposes, is that time out handler able to report what the last bit of code to run before the time out occurred is? That seems like it would be useful to log so I could figure out what is getting stuck.

Comment: Nothing stops you from updating a variable with the current step.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about that -- I wasn't sure if there was something to do it automatically. But, barring that, yes, that sounds like a good plan.

Comment: So when the program hits the point it fails to terminate, it also fails to terminate with this code. It works fine as long as everything is working fine (although if I set the alarm for a reasonable amount of time, it shouldn't ever fire if everything is working fine), but if one of the threads goes awry, it must be freezing the program in such a way that this function can't run/terminate the script.

Comment: I haven't seen any code to terminate the script, nor was that discussed in any way, so I have no idea what you're talking about

Comment: My original code (above) was an attempt to set `$SIG{alarm}` to execute a customized form of `die` with some output comments. The minimal, reproducible code I posted didn't report a lot of useful data, but did _attempt_ to terminate when teh alarm went off, so that was always what I was attempting to do. (E.g. the reason I wanted the alarm was to catch when a thread /should/ have finished, but got stuck, preventing the script from ending as it should have. In any case, I carried that over into what I put in the handler in your code.

Comment: Right now I replaced your "# .... handle timeout ... " spot with `die "Out of time";`